# Best way to implement optional modules for node.js app

Tags: node.js

I'm looking to create an app with optional modules that I will not know the names of in the application.

For example, imagine outlook, but the calendar/tasklist/mail pieces are optional components, you would `npm install outlook-framework` then create your app that requires "outlook-framework" but then I would like to import all packages installed that start with "outlook-". So I can `npm install outlook-mail` and that gives me email support, same for `outlook-calendar`, or even something I didn't write, maybe `outlook-twitter` or `outlook-rss` (or `thirdpary-outlook-module`)

Is there some existing mechanism for loading modules like this? Or does anyone have any better ideas for loading unknown, optional modules?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided that the packages will need to have a manifest, like "outlook-manifest.json" and to load the modules, I'll list directories in node_modules, find directories with a manifest, and load those.